# Adding a border to and Image in my code

Tags: python, image, border

Help, I need to put a border on the image displayed from the code below. How do I do this? The code below pulls up the image, and now i need a border. Help.. **All of this code is Python**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
LoganCaroline_1_4_7: Merge images
'''
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import os.path
import numpy as np      # “as” lets us use standard abbreviations

'''Read the image data'''
# Get the directory of this python script
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) 
# Build an absolute filename from directory + filename
filename = os.path.join(directory, 'family1.jpg')
# Read the image data into an array
img = plt.imread(filename)

'''Show the image data'''
# Create figure with 1 subplot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
# Show the image data in a subplot
ax.imshow(img, interpolation='none')
# Show the figure on the screen
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a slightly larger array that is black and fill the central pixels with your image.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def frame_image(img, frame_width):
    b = frame_width # border size in pixel
    ny, nx = img.shape[0], img.shape[1] # resolution / number of pixels in x and y
    if img.ndim == 3: # rgb or rgba array
        framed_img = np.zeros((b+ny+b, b+nx+b, img.shape[2]))
    elif img.ndim == 2: # grayscale image
        framed_img = np.zeros((b+ny+b, b+nx+b))
    framed_img[b:-b, b:-b] = img
    return framed_img

img = np.random.rand(456, 333, 3)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax1.imshow(img, interpolation='none')
ax2.imshow(frame_image(img, 20), interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm in a class and just learning all of this. I tried to do something similar to this and it told me that "image" wasn't defined. Will I get that message back by using this code or will this work? And if I do get that message back, how can I define an image? Is that a thing?

Comment: In the code snippet that you posted, there is no variable `image`, only a variable `img`. Nobody can help you if you don't post: 1) the exact code + any data used (such as the image file), and 2) the exact error message. The code that I posted will work combined with the code that you posted. Just append my code to your snippet.

Comment: The code that I had when I posted this question was all the code i had in the program. I have added what you had and now it shows my image, and your static image plus your static image with a border. all I need now is to replace the static in your image with mine. How do I do this?

Comment: Just delete the line `img = np.random.rand(456, 333, 3)` . That line creates the "static image". There is a lot more that you could prune, but that one is the most important one.

Comment: There is no error message at the moment and all of mine combined with yours is the exact code. The image that I put in is "family1.jpg" being pulled from my files. Below is a link to my image that I'm trying to put a border on. https://www.google.com/search?q=pexels+family+images&safe=strict&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj15Mex7ZzTAhVL8GMKHRGcB0IQ_AUIBigB&biw=1920&bih=950#imgrc=64B0cUMiLz_y7M:

Comment: That fixed all my problems. Thank you so much. You are credited in the code as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answer, if you want customizable RGB colors (3 dimensions images) for the border color:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

def frame_image(img, frame_width):
    b = frame_width # border size in pixel
    ny, nx = img.shape[0], img.shape[1] # resolution / number of pixels in x and y
    framed_img = Image.new('RGB', (b+ny+b, b+nx+b), (255, 0, 0)) # RGB color tuple
    framed_img = np.array(framed_img.getdata()).reshape(framed_img.size[0], framed_img.size[1], 3)
    framed_img[b:-b, b:-b] = img
    return framed_img

img = np.random.rand(456, 333, 3)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax1.imshow(img, interpolation='none')
ax2.imshow(frame_image(img*255, 20), interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

Output example

[image: 1]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).